# Can I join two tables while creating a new column?

Tags: join, multiple-columns

I have two tables - NETWORK and SITE. network has site_z and site_a, while SITE has a column called site_name.  I would like to join them in a way that creates new fields. So that when site_z=site_name i create new column called z_site_name; and when site_a=site_name I create a new column called a_site_name.
Please advice. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please clarify the question.  Show data examples and the result you want.  Also please provide any methods you've tried and how the result was undesirable.  There is simply not enough information here to provide a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
select s1.site_name site_z_name,s2.site_name site_a_name
from network n left outer join 
site s1 on n.site_z=s1.site_name
left outer join site s2
on n.site_a=s2.site_name
```

this will give you a table that has both columns propagated with respective names.

Comment: hmm, for some reason it says i am missing a keyword right here: as s1 on

Comment: You can try removing the as clause..it may be be DB specific, updating the answer to reflect

Comment: Anytime, please remember to mark my answer as  solving it for you :)